# Adding @PreAuthorize on service layer or controller layer?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I wonder what is the recommended way of applying security constraints with Spring Security?
I have read that you should secure your service layer so that is what I have done. Now, looking at my controller I have some questions.

1. Is it correct to not have authorization annotations in the controller layer?
2. Is the controller layer meant to only be authorized in a coarse grained way using the `intercept-url` elements in the XML app-context?
3. If you only specify `ROLE_USER` as the minimum role in the `intercept-url` element for your app. And then you specify that a certain method in the service layer requires `ROLE_ADMIN`, then you potentially allow some of the code in the controller to execute because the admin constraint isn't nesaccary the first thing in the controller method. **However**, if the assumptions on the questions above are right, then it won't be a problem because you have set the admin role on that particular endpoint in the XML anyway.

Comment: So stupid SO have started to become. Closing and downvoting for everything.